# Which object corresponds to the clicked marker? Mapbox onInfoWindowClick

Tags: android, mapbox, infowindow

I got a list of Spots which are shown on a Mapbox (android app) as markers. When the user clicks a marker, the InfoWindow pops up. I wanted to add a ClickListener to that InfoWindow so that when the user clicks it, I redirect him to a page with more info about that Spot.

Markers don't have a setId, setTag, or anything alike. So how can I know which object in my list corresponds to that clicked marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that inheriting is possible, and [here's](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5370) one possible solution:

Your custom marker containing a tag (or whatever else you wanna add to it):

```
public class UrlMarker extends Marker {

private String tag;

public UrlMarker(BaseMarkerOptions baseMarkerOptions, String tag) {
    super(baseMarkerOptions);
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}
}
```

And your custom BaseMarkerOptions class:

```
public class UrlMarkerOptions extends BaseMarkerOptions<UrlMarker, UrlMarkerOptions> {

private String tag;

public UrlMarkerOptions tag(String name) {
    tag = name;
    return getThis();
}

public UrlMarkerOptions() {
}

private UrlMarkerOptions(Parcel in) {
    position((LatLng) in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader()));
    snippet(in.readString());
    String iconId = in.readString();
    Bitmap iconBitmap = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
    Icon icon = IconFactory.recreate(iconId, iconBitmap);
    icon(icon);
    tag(in.readString());
}

@Override
public UrlMarkerOptions getThis() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public UrlMarker getMarker() {
    return new UrlMarker(this, tag);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<UrlMarkerOptions> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<UrlMarkerOptions>() {
    public UrlMarkerOptions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new UrlMarkerOptions(in);
    }

    public UrlMarkerOptions[] newArray(int size) {
        return new UrlMarkerOptions[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeParcelable(position, flags);
    out.writeString(snippet);
    out.writeString(icon.getId());
    out.writeParcelable(icon.getBitmap(), flags);
    out.writeString(tag);
}

}
```

How to use:

```
UrlMarkerOptions myMarker = new UrlMarkerOptions("object-id");
mapboxMap.addMarker(myMarker);
```

Comment: Hello leone, What goes in for "object-id". Are these two different class files?

Comment: Hi @Indark. I'm not sure if I understood your question. Would you please elaborate? In either way, if you're thinking of using markers on mapbox, I think they've been deprecated. I think you should now use features instead. I'd recommend reading something up to date on mapbox website.

Comment: Hello @leoneboaventura - Was little confused. Got it to work. Thanks much for the prompt response. Much appreciated.